# Combinatorics with percentage constraints

Tags: combinatorics

Say I have a $K$-component alloy system, where the $K$ components are chosen from $N$ possible metal elements ($N>K$), and the concentration of each component always ranges from $a$% to $b$%. Two alloys are considered to be different if any metal content differs by 1%. If we don't distinguish the arrangement of the components (i.e. the order doesn't matter), what is the total number of unique alloy compositions?

For now I only know if we assume the concentrations of all compoenents are always equal, the total number of unique alloy compositions is $\displaystyle{N \choose K} = \frac{N!}{(N-K)!K!}$. But how should we take into account the percentage constraint?

Edit: the percentages are restricted to only integers. To make a component considered as "exists" in the alloy, obviously it has to be at least having a percentage of 1%, thus we always have $K−1 \le a \le b \le 100−K+1$.

To give you some idea: let's say $K=3,a=2,b=98$, we first choose 3 components from the $N$ elements, then the first component can take a percentage equal to $2,3,\ldots,98$, but when the first component takes a percentage of 98% for example, the other two components can only both taking a percentage of 1%.

Comment: I do not completely understand, are all percentages integer? Otherwise it sounds like there are uncountably many combinations, $p$% metal A and $(100-p)$% metal B for any $0\leq p \leq 100$.

Comment: @SamZackrisson Yes all integers

Answer (score 3):

For starters, consider first the case that the concentration is not restricted, so $a=1$ and $b=100$. Then we find the number of alloys by first selecting $K$ out of $N$ elements, in ${N\choose K}$ ways, and then counting the number of [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $100$ into $K$ positive integer parts, which is ${99\choose K-1}$. So the total number $A$ of alloys is
$$A={N\choose K}{99\choose K-1}.$$
Sanity check: take $K=2$, then for the first alloy we can take a percentage equal to $1,2,3\ldots 99$, and the second alloy fills that up to 100, so $A={N\choose 2}{99\choose 1}=\tfrac{1}{2}N(N-1)\times 99$.

For the general case we need the number of compositions of 100 into $K$ integer parts from the interval $[a,b]$. This number $[x^{100}]_P$ is the coefficient of $x^{100}$ of the polynomial
$$P(x)=\left(\sum_{s=a}^b x^s\right)^K,$$
and then
$$A={N\choose K}\times [x^{100}]_P .$$

*Q: Is there a more explicit formula for $[x^{100}]_P$?*

Comment: Think of when $K=3,a=2,b=98$, the first component can take a percentage equal to $2,3,...,98$, but when it takes for example 98%, the other two components have to be all taking a percentage of 1%. (Obviously to make a component considered as "exists" in the alloy, it has to be at least have a pecentage of 1%, thus $K−1\le a \le b \le 100-K+1$. This is not stated in the question but I hope this is clear).

Comment: sure, the generating function for $A$ takes that into account automatically